# Python hashlib returning the same hash

Tags: python, flask, hash

I'm getting a file via Flask and trying to hash it (twice) in order to see if it's in the database.

API route:

```
@app.route("/file_upload", methods=['POST'])
def file_upload():
uploaded_files = request.files.getlist("pdf")
for file in uploaded_files:
    logger.info(f"Processing item {file.filename}")
    # Check if file is already in database
    file_hash = md5_it(file.read())  # !! FIRST HASH
    print(file_hash)
    in_db = get_file(file_hash)
    if in_db:
        logger.info(f"File already in the database, skipping...")
        # File already in database, skipping OCR
        print(in_db)
        text_pdf = in_db.text
        pass
    else:
        logger.debug("Doing OCR...")
        ocred_pdf = ocr_pdf(file)

        logger.debug("Extracting text...")
        text_pdf = read_pdf(file.filename, ocred_pdf)

        logger.debug("Saving to DB")
        create_file(file.read(), ocred_pdf, file.filename, text_pdf) # !! SECOND HASH

return text_pdf
```

The hashing function looks like this:

```
def md5_it(file):
    return hashlib.md5(file).hexdigest()
```

I just keep getting one hash from the first hashing and another hash later on, on the same file. If i hash it twice at the beginning,there are two different hashes and any other file passed will return that last hash. I've tried a bunch of different approaches into changing the hashing method but still no result. Any idea would be helpful. I believe i need to re-instantiate the hashfunction (maybe) but as far as i know, anything inside md5_it function should go out of scope once returned.

Comment: The repeated hash is "d41d...427e", I assume?  After you've called `file.read()`, the current position will now be at the end of the file.  Any further calls to `.read()` will return an empty string - you need to do `file.seek(0)` between uses of the file, to rewind to the beginning.

Comment: Yep... damn. This can be marked as an answer. Thanks!